# material-ui defining styles in custom theme

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using react with material-ui, and I want to override the theme to match my own needs, I saw that you can change all of the properties of each component, but I tried to change the style of the appbar but nothing happend.

Here is what I tried:

```
let theme = {
    appBar: {
        style:{
            height: 128
        }
    }
}
```

I know I can just change the height of the appbar but lets say I want to change something that is not a property, like the 'top' in the drawer's style, like this:

```
let theme= {
    drawer:{
        style:{
            top: 64
        }
    }
}
```

So how can I do that?

Comment: Could you please clearify the question/s? It seems you have two questions, right?

Comment: Just one questions, how could I define the style of the component in the theme object?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the values without the style prop.

So instead of:

```
let theme = {
    appBar: {
        style:{
            height: 128
        }
    }
}
```

Change to:

```
let theme = {
    appBar: {            
        height: 128
    }
}

//Example
const muiTheme = getMuiTheme(theme);
...
```

Comment: yes what what about properties that can be changed only in the style?

Comment: If it is properties that don't exist in material-ui's theme, you don't need to override them, and you could simply use regular old school css styling using selectors. In other words, if it is not a key in the material-ui theme, it is not predefined, so just style like you used to before.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup only limited range of properties within `theme` object. 
You can discover all supported properties and how they changes the appearance via this [online tool](https://sm-react.github.io/storybook-addon-material-ui/?theme-ind=0&theme-sidebar=true&theme-full=true).
If you don't have what you need in `theme` so you may setup it manually via `style` properties.

Notice, that usually there are some "style" properties in Material-UI components. e.g. `style`, `titleStyle`, `iconStyleLeft`, `iconStyleRight` for `App bar`.

Answer (score -1):

Pachu. For answering your question: "how to change the Material-ui's theme?". You can try it:

```
const muiTheme = getMuiTheme({
   palette: {
     textColor: cyan500,
   },
   appBar: {
     height: 50,
   },
});
```

You can refer this link: http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/themes